# Android Studio все импорты отображает красным

Tags: android

Работал с проектом, компилировал, всё шло в обычном режиме.
Вдруг, при редактировании кода, что то глюкнуло (то есть я не обновлялся, и не делал настроек android studio, не трогал build.gradle) - и практически весь код стал Красным.

При наведении - предлагает "Setup JDK" - а когда щёлкаешь по нему, открывает окно  "Configure SDK".

Необходимые пакеты для компиляции в среде у меня установлены, да и "5 минут тому назад" всё компилировалось на ура.

Что можно посмотреть, для исправления этого недуга?

Что испробовано:
1) Запустил все последние предлагаемые обновления.
2) прописал в переменные среды 
JAVA_HOME      D:\android\jdk
ANDROID_HOME   D:\android\sdk

3) Переустановил JDk с x64 на х86
4) скопировал файлы java.exe javaw.exe  javaws.exe  в папку C:\Windows\SysWOW64

Comment: Попробуйте пересобрать проект.

Comment: Rebuild не помог. 
Кстати, не все импорты оказывается сейчас красные, пока я щёлках, в попытках решить проблему, импорты из раздела 
import android.support.v4.*****  перестали быть красными, остальные красные:
import android.view.*****
import android.os.*****
import android.widget.*****
import org.jsoup.*****
import java.io.*****
import java.util.*****

Comment: открыл предыдущие проекты, они тоже теперь окрашены... дело не в настройках конкретного проекта. Видимо что то со средой случилось.

Comment: Попробуйте почистить кэш студии и перезапустить: **File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart**

Comment: понял вас, спасибо! буду сносить.

Comment: ан нет, не буду сносить. помог совет Бармалея)) как тут плюс вам поставить?))